# Creating/Exposing WCF services from an existing ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, interop, soa

We need to expose some services (i.e. AddressValidatorService, CustomerFinderService) that currently reside in an ASP.NET application to other applications within our organization.  Exposing these services via WCF seems like a natural fit, but I don't see any best-practices for how to pull these common services into a WCF wrapper in such a way that my existing ASP.NET application can continue to use them with minimal code changes and/or awareness that the service they are consuming is no longer in-process.

I'm especially looking for recommendations on how to structure the existing ASP.NET solution and whether to host our new WCF in the same solution or in some new shared WCF solution referenced by both our ASP.NET application and external callers.

Also, is it bad practice to simply promote the DTOs currently only consumed in-process via ASP.NET to full fledged data contracts or is it preferable to create duplicate DTOs that are explicitly decorated with [DataContract]?  The latter seems like a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question:

> Also, is it bad practice to simply promote the DTOs currently only consumed in-process via ASP.NET to full fledged data contracts or is it preferable to create duplicate DTOs that are explicitly decorated with [DataContract]? The latter seems like a maintenance nightmare.

It is considered a bad practice to expose your business model as WCF contracts.  So if your DTOs are replicas of your domain model then it would be a strict no-no, because
 
1. any change in the model would directly effect the contracts and hence all the clients using it 
2. you would be exposing your business "know-how" to the outside world.

The latter can tend to get difficult for any evolving system, but then you have various open source tools (like AutoMapper) that ease your mapping nighmares.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an existing project to WCF, then continue to use it in-process by using a project reference.  It can then be consumed by an eternal source using the WCF client.  A WCF client converts the class name from `ClassName` to `ClassNameClient` when consumed over WCF, but the class will function pretty much the same.

For example:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.DoSomething(withData);
```

Would become:

```
MyClassClient obj = new MyClassClient();
obj.DoSomething(withData);
```

You would publish the WCF project to some endpoint, like `address.example.com`, then use a service reference to the endpoint to reference the code, like a project reference, in your other projects.

Note that while the externally referencing projects would not be impacted by the change or know that the data is going over the network, if you have chatty calls to the project in question, it will definitely take a performance hit.  You may want to consolidate related methods into single methods to save on round-tripping.

Answer (score 0):

If these are exposed as static page services, there's no magic wrapper -- you're going to need to move code to a standalone service implementation class and put a .svc file in front of it. (Or use WCF4 fileless activation, or a service factory, but that's getting a bit away from the core question here.)

If these are exposed as ASMX, you can actually put an ASMX facade in front of a WCF service class and get basic HTTP/XML/ASMX responses as you would from your legacy ASMX webservices. You an expose that same WCF service class through standard WCF configuration for non-legacy consumers.

Finally, you can expose any WCF service as basicHTTP with serviceMetadata + httpGetEnabled, and you'll get a service endpoint usable by legacy consumers of an ASMX service.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751433.aspx